# the lim of sum of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have to calculate the following:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{n}{n^2+1^2}+\frac{n}{n^2+2^2} + \cdots + \frac{n}{n^2+n^2} )$

I managed to  understand that it is

$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{n}{n^2+1^2}+\frac{n}{n^2+2^2} + \cdots + \frac{n}{n^2+n^2} ) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+i^2}$

but i can't find a way to calculate...

I found that the sequence lower bound is $\frac{1}{2}$ and upper bound is 1, but thats all...

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You inner sum is a Riemann sum:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n}{n^2+i^2}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^2}\approx\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\arctan 1=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}}.$$

Comment: can you show how do you get from the sum to the integral ?
please link to a proof of that
thanks

Comment: @YoavR.: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum - take the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and the integration interval $[0,1]$, to be partitioned into $n$ equals sub-intervals. The Riemann integrability of the function $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ over $[0,1]$ follows from its continuity and gives that your limit equals $\frac{\pi}{4}$ as stated.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$\sum \frac{n}{n^2+i^2}=\frac{1}{n}\sum \frac{1}{1+(\frac{i}{n})^2}$$

then use calculus.

Comment: how?
i have to calculate the limit on $n\to\infty$ not $i\to\infty$

Comment: This expression is the Riemann sum for a particular function.  Taking $n\to \infty$ turns the sum into an integral.

Comment: can you direct me to a proof of this theorem?

Comment: you  suggest that i can apply the limit in a way that i am not familiar with, i know reimann sum.... and i cannot see how it helps me

Comment: Riemann sums are of the form $\sum f(k/n)\Delta{x} $, the sum on the rhs above is of this form with $\Delta{x} = 1/n$ and $f(k/n) = (1 + (k/n)^2)^{-1}$. The limit of this sum is the integral of $f(x)$ from $0$ to $1$, as is done in Jack D'Aurizio's answer.